# At which point of time is a session counted as inactive?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

Ok, In Java, I don't understand what actions tell that a session is and isn't alive.

I used to think that if user has never touched the page and after a period of time, the session will expire.

session.setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60); //15 mins

But let say there is a page call `ajaxChat.jsp` which has a functions to send data back and forward between client and server.

The UserA logined & created a session. He then can enter the `ajaxChat.jsp`. UserB sometimes send messages to UserA via interface on `ajaxChat.jsp`.

UserA just lives the `ajaxChat.jsp` & do something else. Hoever, every 5 mins the UserB send a message to UserA.

The question is that if UserA just leaves `ajaxChat.jsp` there without touching it for more than 30mins, then will the session of User A expire? Note that every 5 mins, `ajaxChat.jsp` receives a new message from UserB.

*I don't understand how Java Session works when it is counted that the session expires?*

*Which actions tell that a session is or isn't alive?*

*At which point of time is a session counted as inactive?*

*What if user has never touched the page but the page has some Ajax calls periodically in the background?*

Comment: In case of ajax calls happening in background session should not expire as it's similar to normal requests from user and the server is still getting the request/respose for that user.

Comment: JSPs don't send messages to each other. A JSP is basically a servlet that receives a HTTP requests, and sends HTML to the corresponding HTTP response. Your session expires if no HTTP request has been received with that session ID for more than 15 minutes. As simple as that. Whether the request is an AJAX request sent by a scheduled JavaScript job, or from a click in the browser, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Here Ajax code in ajaxChat.jsp is responsible for sending and receiving the message. So both USer-A and User-B are using the output of the Servlet generated after JSP translation and compilation. So, do not think it as ajaxChat.jsp page is making communication between the two users.

For the server request that comes after every 5 minutes marking the activity from user irrespective of the call by normal user action or Ajax call. Both are equivalent for the server. Meaning that the server will not count it as inactive session.

If you want to have your application with behavior of expiring session after 15 minutes, you will need to handle on your own.

You can manage a map in application context (key as JSESSIONID cookie value) with your last activity time of user from the specific pages/calls which are interpreted as actions from the user not from Ajax Chat. Testing every time the difference (Last Activity Time - Current Time) and marking the session expired explicitly as sesion.invalidate().